# downloading data in a loop, how often to save that information

Tags: r, loops, download, save

I'm using R, but this question isn't specific to it.  Suppose you've written some loop which downloads a url at each iteration.  You want to to save this data, so you could do so each iteration or hold the information and save it every nth iteration.  Are there any general rules of thumb for doing this?  How slow is it to open and close a file for writing all the time?  What I have in mind is

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
   data <- url("http://...i")
   write.table(data, file="file")
}
```

versus something like this

```
data <- list()
length(data) <- 20
j <- 1
for (i in 1:1000) {
   data[j] <-url("http://...i")
   j <- j+1
   if (j = 20) {j <-1}
   if (i %% 20 == 0) {
      write.table(data, file="file")
      }
   }
```

Comment: What is `j` for in the second bit of code?

Comment: Would it be ok to save a serialized version of the data, using `saveRDS` not `write.table`. This would be significantly quicker. Also do you know the `url` addresses (do they end in `i`?)

Comment: Are the data at each iteration of the same class and shape (i. e. all dataframes with the same fields) ?

Comment: There is probably going to be a tradeoff between the file size and the time it takes to save the object. Also, you obviously won't want to save objects during every loop if you will need to build these back into a single object for later work in R. Without knowing the exact nature of these issues, it's a bit hard to suggest a particular approach.

Comment: i think this is the sort of thing that will depend on your computer, your URL, your internet connection, and probably a lot of other things that are specific to your situation. I'd set up a few test examples and give it a whirl...what works on my Windows 7 64 bit OS with SSD HD and 12 gigs of RAM may not work as well on your machine specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your downloaded data are of the same form, you might want to `append` them to a unique file in which case you can do that at each iteration. Here is a short example:

```
sites<-c("714A","715A","716A")
for(i in 1:length(sites)){
    data<-read.table(file=paste("http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/geology/odp/data/115/",sites[i],"paleomag.txt",sep="/"),sep="\t",header=TRUE)
    #In this example i downloaded paleomagnetic data from deep sea drilling sites.
    ifelse(i==1,h<-TRUE,h<-FALSE)  #Here the idea is that we want to output the column names only the first time.
    write.table(data,file="paleomag_leg115.txt",sep="\t",append=!h,col.names=h,row.names=FALSE)
    }
```